# Visual studio indents C++/CLI incorrectly w.r.t. generic return types

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, c++-cli, indentation, code-formatting

Consider a code snippet like shown next.

```
generic<typename T, typename C>
    where C: IComparable<C>
        C
        PriorityQueue<T, C>::CostOfTop ()
    {
        auto bar = 0;
    }

    generic<typename T, typename C>
        where C: IComparable<C>
            void
            PriorityQueue<T, C>::CheckHeapProperty (int index)
        {
            auto foo = 0;
        }
```

The code is formatted by visual studio 2013.
As you can see, the second function is indented too much, and this stacks when you add more functions.
Clearly, this is wrong. Can it be fixed without putting everything on one line? (as this is undesirable with long types)

Comment: I agree that it's far from perfect, but is there a better alternative that supports C++/CLI .NET?

Comment: It is a bug in the auto-formatter, specific to generic methods.  We can't fix the bug for you, you'll need to report it at connect.microsoft.com.  The only practical workaround is to keep them in a separate file that you #include.